# Spell checker throwing errors?

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I am using the WPF textbox spell checker like this:

```
<TextBox ... SpellCheck.IsEnabled="{Binding EnableSpelling}"... />
```

As you see it's bound to a bool property in my VM that tells it if it should spell check this box or not.  This seems to be working for the most part but I have gotten a handful of users that are getting an occasional error with it.  The confusing thing to me is that the stack trace doesn't show my code at all...  Here is the trace:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Windows.Documents.WinRTSpellerInterop.UnloadDictionary(Object token)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Speller.OnDictionaryUriRemoved(Uri uri)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Speller.OnDictionaryUriAdded(Uri uri)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Speller.SetCustomDictionaries(CustomDictionarySources dictionaryLocations, Boolean add)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor.SetCustomDictionaries(Boolean add)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SpellCheck.OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I've looked around but can't find anything like this.  Plenty of 'key was not present' errors out there but none in spell checker or like this that I could find.  I understand what a key not found error is, but what dictionary is it using and how would I go about fixing it since the stack is entirely in the .NET framework instead of my code?